# problem on python BeautifulSoup and Requests

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup

I'm a complete newbie on programming, I try to program few days and I had some problems with it, pls help me OLZ.
why it is empty? no problem on programming but didnt output data.
.....
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: []

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd 

baseurl = 'https://www.ztore.com'

headers = {
    'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0(Windows NT 10.0; Win64; 64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36'
}
productlinks = []

for x in range(1,6):
    r = requests.get(f'https://www.ztore.com/tc/category/all/grocery/grocery-rewards')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
    productlist = soup.find_all('div', class_='jsx-638078379 jsx-1176293161 ProductItem ')
    for item in productlist:
        for link in item.find_all('a', href=True):
            productlinks.append(baseurl + link['href'])

#testlink = 'https://www.ztore.com/tc/product/reduced-salt-oyster-sauce-cumin-flavour-sauce-6006208-c19669'

productlist = []

for link in productlinks:
    r = requests.get(link, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
    name = soup.find('h2', class_='jsx-891702026').text.strip()
    price = soup.find('span', class_='jsx-891702026 original').text.strip()
    promotion = soup.find('span', class_='jsx-891702026 promotion').text.strip()
    
    product = {
        name,
        price,
        promotion,
        }
        
    productlist.append(product)
    print('Saving:', product['name'])

df = pd.DataFrame(productlist)
print(df.head(15))
```

Comment: Please provide a sufficient description of your problem: what exactly do you want, what did you try, what errors you faced, etc. while writing your question. See here on how to write good question in Stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What is exactly empty? narrow down whole code to fragment that does not work as expected. The more compact (but still reproducible) code is the better.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few problems with your code.

1. Extra space at the end  `class_='jsx-638078379 jsx-1176293161 ProductItem '`
2. `for x in range(1,6):` why are you running it in a loop? Running it once is enough.
3. Few links don't have the classes you're looking for. applying text.strip() without checking will result in an error.

Try the below code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd 

baseurl = 'https://www.ztore.com'

headers = {
    'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0(Windows NT 10.0; Win64; 64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36'
}
productlinks = []

r = requests.get('https://www.ztore.com/tc/category/all/grocery/grocery-rewards')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
# print(soup.prettify())
productlist = soup.find_all('div', class_='jsx-638078379 jsx-1176293161 ProductItem')
# print(productlist)
for item in productlist:
    for link in item.find_all('a', href=True):
        productlinks.append(baseurl + link['href'])

# print(productlinks)
#testlink = 'https://www.ztore.com/tc/product/reduced-salt-oyster-sauce-cumin-flavour-sauce-6006208-c19669'

productlist = []

print(len(productlinks))
for link in productlinks:
    r = requests.get(link, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
    name=""
    price=""
    promotion=""
    if soup.find('h2', class_='jsx-891702026'):
        name = soup.find('h2', class_='jsx-891702026').text.strip()
    if soup.find('span', class_='jsx-891702026 original'):
        price = soup.find('span', class_='jsx-891702026 original').text.strip()
    if soup.find('span', class_='jsx-891702026 promotion'):
        promotion = soup.find('span', class_='jsx-891702026 promotion').text.strip()
    
    product = {
        name,
        price,
        promotion,
        }
        
    productlist.append(product)
    print('Saving:', product)

df = pd.DataFrame(productlist)
print(df.head(15))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use
`df.to_excel("file.xlsx")` at the end for exporting your dataframe as an Excel file.
You can also specify your own filename.

Answer (score 0):

Use this to read and show the excel file output.

```
df= pd.read_csv('filename.csv')
print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

First have a look at the HTML source. Then see, what we can extract directly.

#### Copy the relevant HTML portion to a text-editor

... or open in browser's web inspector

```html
1    <div class="jsx-950115395 CategoryProductList">
2        <div class="jsx-950115395 products desktop">
3            <div class="jsx-4061644943 ProductList root">
4                <div class="jsx-638078379 jsx-1176293161 ProductItem ">
5                    <a href="/tc/product/seasoned-soy-sauce-gold-soy-sauce-1023790-c19669">
6                        <div class="jsx-638078379 jsx-1176293161 img">
7                            <div style="">
8                              <img alt="李錦記 - 蒸魚豉油+金醬油 - 410MLX2+150ML" srcSet="" src="https://image.ztore.com/images/ztore/production/product/368px/1023790_1.jpg?1531838949"/>
9                              <img alt="李錦記 - 蒸魚豉油+金醬油 - 410MLX2+150ML" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7">
10                           </div>
11                       </div>
12                       <div class="jsx-638078379 jsx-1176293161 name_bbd">
13                           <div title="李錦記 - 蒸魚豉油+金醬油 - 410MLX2+150ML" class="jsx-638078379 jsx-1176293161 name text-overflow">
14                               <div class="jsx-911327278 TruncateBox"><span class="jsx-638078379 jsx-1176293161">李錦記 - 蒸魚豉油+金醬油 </span></div>
15                           </div>
16                       </div>
17                       <div class="jsx-638078379 jsx-1176293161 packsize"><span class="jsx-638078379 jsx-1176293161 vmiddle">410MLX2+150ML</span></div>
18                       <div class="jsx-638078379 jsx-1176293161 rating"></div>
19                       <div class="jsx-638078379 jsx-1176293161 price">
20                           <span class="jsx-638078379 jsx-1176293161 promotion"><span class="jsx-638078379 jsx-1176293161 dollar-sign">$</span>18.9</span>
21                           <span class="jsx-638078379 jsx-1176293161 original">$<!-- -->24.9</span>
22                       </div>
23                   </a>
25                   <div class="jsx-638078379 jsx-1176293161 label-ctnr">
26                       <a href="/tc/product/seasoned-soy-sauce-gold-soy-sauce-1023790-c19669">
27                           <div title="李錦記 - 蒸魚豉油+金醬油 - 410MLX2+150ML" class="jsx-638078379 jsx-1176293161 link"></div>
28                       </a>
30                   </div>
31               </div>
```

I have extracted the **product-list** with the first product-item as sample.
This extract I have prepared for analysis:

1. formatted with line-breaks (pretty print) to recognize structure.
2. removed what seemed unimportant  for content extraction (web-design/layout).
3. added line-numbers to discuss it further

#### Analysis of Content and Structure

line in above extract referenced in parentheses:

- (3): the **product-list** is a `div` with classes `jsx-4061644943 ProductList root`
- it contains 32 items as `div` with classes `jsx-638078379 jsx-1176293161 ProductItem` (the trailing space in original HTML source is neglected - does not work with *BeautifulSoup*!)
- (4-31) each item contains all information you are looking for:

  1. (12) title or **name** in `div` with class `name_bbd`
  2. (17) **packsize** in `div` with class `packsize`
  3. (18) **rating** (contents removed here) in `div` with class `rating`
  4. (19) **prize** in `div` with class `price`

     1. (20) **promotion** in `span` with class `promotion` (children `span` for `dollar-sign` !)
     2. (21) **original** in `span` with class `original`
  5. (6) **images** of the product in `div` with class `img` then (8) first child `img` having attribute `srcSet` whith URL of the image in `src`
  6. (25) **link** to the product details page in `div` with class `label-ctnr` then (26) children `a`

**Note:** all product item attributes have the CSS classes `jsx-638078379 jsx-1176293161` prepended. However, for readability and easier distinction, I left them out in the numbered list.

### Solution

Here is the improved code:

- the upper part, commented *Version 1*, contains your approach - issues fixed and code improved (decomposed the problem into 3 functions)
- the lower part, commented *Version 2*, contains my approach - direct extraction of product attributes (decomposed the problem into 2 functions)
- the last if-block is the main-function for running (currently Version 2)

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

# Version 1
def to_urls(item_elements, base_url):
    urls = []
    for item in item_elements:
        for link in item.find_all('a', href=True):
            if '/product' in link['href']:
                urls.append(base_url + link['href'])
    return urls


def scrape_product_links(base_url):
    print('loading product list ..')
    r = requests.get(f'{base_url}/tc/category/all/grocery/grocery-rewards')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
    products = soup.find_all('div', class_='ProductItem')
    print("found products:", len(products))
    return to_urls(products, base_url)


def scrape_product_pages(product_links):
    product_list = []
    for link in product_links:
        print('following link:', link)
        r = requests.get(link)  # , headers=headers)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
        # produce name
        n = soup.find('h2', class_='jsx-891702026')
        name = n.text.strip() if n else ''
        # original price
        p = soup.find('span', class_='jsx-891702026 original')
        price = p.text.strip() if p else ''
        # promotion price
        promo = soup.find('span', class_='jsx-891702026 promotion')
        promotion = promo.text.strip() if promo else ''
        # a product list with  name, price, and promotion price
        product = {'name': name, 'price': price, 'promotion': promotion}
        print('adding:', product)
        product_list.append(product)
    return product_list


# Version 2
def to_products(items, base_url):
    product_list = []
    for it in items:
        # produce name
        n = it.find('div', class_='name_bbd')
        name = n.text.strip() if n else ''
        # original price
        p = it.find('span', class_='original')
        price = p.text.strip() if p else ''
        # promotion price
        promo = it.find('span', class_='promotion')
        promotion = promo.text.strip() if promo else ''
        # a product list with  name, price, and promotion price
        product = {'name': name, 'price': price, 'promotion': promotion}
        print('adding:', product)
        product_list.append(product)
    return product_list


def scrape_products(base_url):
    print('loading product list ..')
    r = requests.get(f'{base_url}/tc/category/all/grocery/grocery-rewards')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
    product_items = soup.find_all('div', class_='ProductItem')
    print("found product items:", len(product_items))
    return to_products(product_items, base_url)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    base_url = 'https://www.ztore.com'

    # version 1
    # urls = scrape_product_links(base_url)
    # print('product urls collected:', len(urls))
    # products = scrape_product_pages(urls)

    # version 2
    products = scrape_products(base_url)
    print('products collected:', len(products))

    df = pd.DataFrame(products)
    print(df.head(15))
```